# Probability, possibly binomial?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-theorem, multinomial-coefficients

There is a new pill for pregnant women. If this pill is taken, there is a probability of $0.5$ that the woman will not have a baby, $0.45$ that she will have one baby, and $0.05$ that she will have twins. An observation was conducted on $100$ women. What is the probability that the number of babies observed does not exceed $60$?

Comment: If you don't mind using technology to calculate, it would be the coefficient of $x^{60}$ in the expansion of $(0.5 + 0.45x+0.05x^2)^{100}(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{60})$

Comment: This site works better if you show what you have tried